# Why is this simple jQuery on click event not working?

Tags: jquery

jQuery is loaded (version 1.8.3) in my header.

but if I try this:

```
<button id="idiot" type="button">Generate</button>

<script> 

$( document ).ready(function () {

  $("#idiot").on("click", "#idiot", function () {

    alert( 'working');

  });

});

</script>
```

I get nothing.

Why i want afer click on this button the alert popup. But rigth now it's not working. Why?

Comment: remove the 2nd argument `#idiot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#idiot").on("click", function () {
    alert('working');
});
```

If the element is dynamically added to the DOM you will need to delegate it to the closest static parent element like this

```
$(document).on("click","#idiot", function () {
    alert('working');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6P7Us/)

Documentation for .on() [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function () {

  $("body").on("click", "#idiot", function () {

    alert( 'working');

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) where the element does not have any descendants. If your element is a static one(create by the markup when it is loaded) then there is no need to use event delegation, you can register the handler as below in the dom ready handler

```
//shortcut for document ready
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#idiot").on("click",function () {
        alert('working');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3KhwW/)

If the element is created after dom ready by a script then you need to use event delegation in that case you need to bind the handler to a already present element like the document object or any other static element then pass the second argument as a string for the dynamic element selector

```
$(document).on("click", '#idiot', function () {
    alert('working');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :-

http://jsfiddle.net/SXzK7/

```
<button id="genius" type="button">Generate</button>

 $("#genius").click(function () {

    alert( 'you are a genius');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to select a descendent.

Use the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function () {

  $("#idiot").on("click", onIdiotButtonPress);

});

function onIdiotButtonPress(event){
        alert( 'working');
}
```

[Here is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78f6J/2/)